# How do I get networking to work for a Live USB?

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, live-usb

I'm working on configuring a bootable Live USB with Ubuntu on it (13.04 to be specific) that I can take with me anywhere and boot up on any PC with a standard BIOS and USB port, but I seem to be running into a problem...

The networking capabilities don't always seem to work.  I'm guessing it has to do with not having the proper module available, but I'm lost on how to best prepare against this.

Is there a way to install or provide just about any network and wireless module I can get my hands on?

Relatively new to Ubuntu, and much searching hasn't seemed to yield an answer.  Any help here would be significantly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of *lspci* please?

Comment: It's going to vary from computer to computer.  Sometimes it's a Broadcom, sometimes a Centrino, sometimes an Atheros, etc.

Comment: Oh you're talking in general?

Comment: I am.  I could insert this Live USB into virtually any PC with a USB port and have it boot up.  The problem becomes, how do I prepare the greatest possibility that I will have the necessary NIC module for that machine on my Live USB, and that it will load on boot and work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out your Wireless or Ethernet NIC with `lspci | grep Wireless` or `lspci | grep Network` then find the module associated with it and load it with `modprobe <module>`.

Comment: This isn't something that is automatically detected and loaded by the kernel during boot?